# Silverlight server socket

Tags: silverlight, sockets

I am developing a Silverlight app and I want to open server socket on it. But I can not bind socket to a specific end point. Is there a possibility to open socket listener in Silverlight application? 
   Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Silverlight sockets are very restrictive.
You cannot create server sockets and you can use the Socket class to connect to a server only through the ports 4502-4534. Also, the server must be configured to accept your connection.

MSDN resources:

- [Working with Sockets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc296248%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)
- [Socket class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)
- [Network Security Access Restrictions in Silverlight](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645032%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)